# Does the integral $\int_0^1\sin(1/x)\, \mathrm{d}x$ converge?

Tags: definite-integrals

I am interested in proving that the integral $$\int_{0^+}^1\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\,\mathrm d x$$ converges.  Can someone show me step by step please?

Comment: It is continuous on $(0,1]$ and bounded. So yes.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint.* Make the substitution $xy=1.$ Then the integral becomes $$\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\sin y}{y^2}\mathrm dy,$$ which you should be able to show converges.